# Rule of five and move semantics for a string class

Tags: c++, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management

I have been learning about the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) and I tried to implement an example myself. It all works exactly as I'd expect, but I was wondering if I've missed any obvious issues or easier/faster ways of implementing the constructors and operators.

```
class string {
public:
    string() : data(nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Default ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    string(const char * p, size_t size) : m_size(size) { //default constructor
        std::cout << "Special ctor" << std::endl;
        data = new char[m_size];
        memcpy(data, p, m_size);
    }
    ~string() noexcept { //default destructor
        std::cout << "Default dtor\r\n";
        delete[] data;
    }
    string(const string & str) { //copy constructor
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
        m_size = str.m_size;
        data = new char[m_size];
        memcpy(data,str.data,m_size); 
    }
    string(string && str)  { //move constructor
        std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
        m_size = str.m_size;
        data = str.data; //swap the values
        str.data = nullptr;
    }
    string& operator=(const string & str)  { //copy operator
        std::cout << "Copy assignment" << std::endl;
        if (this == &str) return * this;
        delete[] data; //can safely delete a nullptr
        m_size = str.m_size;
        char * new_data = new char[m_size]; //we have to make a copy as this is not the move operator
        memcpy(new_data,str.data,m_size); 
        data = new_data;
        return * this;
    }
    string& operator=(string && str) { //move assignment operator
        std::cout << "Move assignment" << std::endl;
        if (this == &str) return * this;
        delete[] data; //delete the old data, will be ok because data is always initialised to nullptr
        m_size = str.m_size; 
        data = str.data; //swap over the pointers
        str.data = nullptr; 
        return * this;
    }

    string& operator+=(const string & str) {
        size_t new_size = m_size + str.m_size; //we need to create a new block of memory with the new appropriate size
        char * new_data = new char[new_size];
        memmove(new_data,data,m_size); //move the old memory
        strcat(new_data,str.data); //concat the new memory
        delete[] data; //delete the old data
        m_size = new_size;
        data = new_data;
        return *this;
    } 

    string operator+(const string & str) {
        return static_cast<string&&>(string(*this) += str);   //could be replaced with std::move() but I use static cast for education purposes
    }

private:
    char * data;
    size_t m_size;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const string& s) {
        os << s.data << "\r\n";
        return os;
    }
};

    int main() {
        const char t1[] = "text";
        const char t2[] = "more text";
        const char * p1 = t1;
        const char * p2 = t2;
        string a(p1,sizeof(t1));
        string b(p2,sizeof(t2));
        string c(a);
        string d(a + b);
        string e;
        a += b;
        e = d;
        c = b + a;

        std::cout << "a:\t" << a;
        std::cout << "b:\t" << b;
        std::cout << "c:\t" << c;
        std::cout << "d:\t" << d;
        std::cout << "e:\t" << e;


        return 0;
    }
```

I ran it with valgrind and recieved the following output: I am concerned that there are 11 uses of alloc and only 10 frees? I am vaguely familiar with the difference but not confident enough to tell if it's a mistake I've made or expected output?

```
==24703== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24703==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==24703==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 10 frees, 73,833 bytes allocated
==24703== 
==24703== LEAK SUMMARY:
==24703==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24703==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24703==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24703==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==24703==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24703== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==24703== 
==24703== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24703== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: In your default constructor, you forgot to initialize `m_size`. [Don't assume it will be automatically initialized to 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053057/do-i-have-to-initialize-simple-class-member-variables).

Comment: One thing that surprised me is that the ostream output operator is in a `private:` section, but is still accessible from `main()` - presumably being declared `friend` makes it visible?  I'm still learning here...

Answer (score 5):

#### Comments

Let's consider one of your constructors, and its accompanying comment:

```
string(const char * p, size_t size) : m_size(size) { //default constructor
```

At least in my opinion, this has at least two obvious problems. This first problem is that the comment is just wrong. A default constructor is one that can be invoked without supplying any arguments. In this case, two arguments must be supplied, so it's not a default ctor.

The second problem is almost simpler. As it stands right now, the comment is pointless. If the comment were corrected (or the code changed so it really was a default constructor), it would still wouldn't give any useful information. It's just telling me what's already obvious from the function's parameter list--it's a default ctor if and only if it can be invoked without supplying any arguments.

Comments should convey information that's *not* immediately obvious from the code itself. Most often, this is things like *why* you wrote the code the way it is.

The same applies to most of the other comments as well--everything they try to convey is either wrong or obvious (or, as above, both).

#### Non-templated string type

The days of strings supporting only `char` as the data type are (IMO) long past. Whether you like Unicode or not, it's better to support it (and for a string, it's much cleaner to manipulate UTF-32 than UTF-8).

#### Array `new`

The array form of `new` should generally be avoided. In the *specific* case of `char` (or `unsigned char`) it's marginally less evil than usual, but I'd advise avoiding it in general. For containers (and IMO, `string` is a container) you want to use `operator new` to allocate "raw" memory, then use placement new to construct objects in that raw memory. It's kind of overkill in the specific case of `char`, but at worst it's harmless, and at best it's a drastic improvement (it leaves the unused part of the memory as raw memory, where `new []` always creates objects in all the memory you allocate).

#### `operator+`

I'm not particularly fond of your current implementation of `operator+`. It works, but (IMO) is fairly easy for somebody to misinterpret in subtle ways that could lead to problems down the road.

I'd do pretty much the same things, but split it into smaller pieces that made the intent a little more obvious:

```
string operator+(const string & str) const {
    string r(*this);
    r += str;
    return r;
}
```

I'd have to think things through in detail to be sure, there's at least a reasonable chance that this is actually more efficient. In particular, it allows copy elision of the return value, where casting to an rvalue (whether done explicitly or in the form of `std::move`) can inhibit that.

#### Alternative Rule

In most case, you want to follow the [rule of zero](https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero) rather than the rule of five. In simple form, this says you should delegate essentially all the resource management to a class (most often `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`) devoted solely to that purpose, so your class only needs to deal with whatever it's really supposed to do. In the case of a (non-COW) string, each string representation has only a single owner, so this should be `std::unique_ptr`.

#### Copy assignment

Your current copy assignment operator isn't safe in the face of exceptions. Right now you have a sequence of deleting the existing data, *then* allocating new space, and then copying the new data into the new space. If (for example) that `new` throws an exception, your string won't contain either the old data or the new data. Since it's a constructed string, its destructor will execute when that scope is exited. That will attempt to delete the buffer pointed to by its `data`--which you just deleted, so you get a double delete, giving undefined behavior.

One easy way to get defined behavior is the copy and swap idiom, which could look something like this:

```
string& operator=(string str) {
    std::cout << "Copy assignment\n";
    using std::swap;
    swap(data, str.data);
    swap(m_size, str.m_size);
    return *this;
}
```

Since we pass the parameter by value, the copy constructor is invoked to create a string for the parameter. We then essentially do a move from there to the target. To keep things as simple as possible, we swap the guts of the two strings, so when the function returns, the parameter goes out of scope, and gets destroyed automatically.

In this case, the allocation happens in the ctor, so if it throws, this function is never invoked at all. The function itself contains only operations that we know can't throw, so we don't have to worry about what would happen if an exception were thrown in the middle of it.

This isn't the only possible way, of course, but it's one way that's pretty easy to get right. More important, perhaps, is establishing the basic pattern:

Phase 1: carry out things that might throw, but don't affect any existing data if they do.
Phase 2: carry out operation that affect existing data, but can't throw.

This way, if anything throws, Phase 2 never happens at all, so existing data can never be affected. If phase 2 starts, it always executes completely. Therefore, we always get either the state from before we started this operation at all, or else the state after it finished completely. The outside world will never see an intermediate state.

Of course, move assignment can be handled much the same way, except taking an rvalue reference as the parameter. We can still swap the "guts" of the current string with those of the parameter, and then let the dtor take care of destroying the parameter when it goes out of scope:

```
string& operator=(string && str) {
    std::cout << "Move assignment\n";
    using std::swap;
    swap(data, str.data);
    swap(m_size, str.m_size);
    return *this;
}
```

#### Use of `strcat`

As it stands right now, I'd call your use of `strcat` (e.g., in `operator+=`) basically a bug. To use `strcat`, you'd need to guarantee that every string contains exactly one NUL character at its very end.

As it stands now, a string can be created that contains NUL characters in its middle. A string can also be created that doesn't contain any NUL character at its end.

To work correctly, you could use `memcpy` for both operations:

```
string& operator+=(const string & str) {
    size_t new_size = m_size + str.m_size;
    char * new_data = new char[new_size];
    mempy(new_data, data, m_size); 
    memcpy(new_data+m_size, str.data, str.m_size); 
    delete[] data;
    m_size = new_size;
    data = new_data;
    return *this;
}
```

Note that your use of `memmove` would work correctly, but was overkill. `memmove` guarantees correct behavior even if the old and new locations might overlap. To do that, it has to check for overlap, and copy from beginning to end for overlap in one direction, and end to beginning for overlap in the other direction. In this case, we know there will never be any overlap, so we can use `memcpy` which only supports non-overlapping buffers (so it avoids checking for overlap).

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code, Valgrind reports 11 allocations and a matching 11 frees, with no leaks.  So I don't see why your run indicated a non-freed block.

I did have to add includes for `<cstring>` and `<iostream>` to get it to compile - please don't omit your includes, even if the code is long!  Other than that, this code was complete; it's clear and easy to read.

Some observations:

### Initializers

`g++ -Weffc++` turns up some missing initialisers that are worth addressing.  For example:

> ```
> string() : data(nullptr) {
>     std::cout << "Default ctor" << std::endl;
> }
> ```

Would be better if it also initialized `m_size`:

```
string()
    : data(nullptr),
      m_size(0)
{
    std::clog << "Default ctor" << std::endl;
}
```

And this one (the comment lies):

> ```
> string(const char * p, size_t size) : m_size(size) { //default constructor
>     std::cout << "Special ctor" << std::endl;
>     data = new char[m_size];
>     memcpy(data, p, m_size);
> }
> ```

could be

```
string(const char *p, size_t size)
    : data(new char[size]),
      m_size(size)
{
    std::clog << "Converting ctor" << std::endl;
    std::memcpy(data, p, m_size);
}
```

I prefer one initialiser per line, as I do for assignments - but you're welcome to disagree.

### Constructors - general

I'd add a constructor that takes a null-terminated string:

```
string(const char *p) : string(p, strlen(p)) {}
```

### Assignment operator

You can simplify your assignment operator using the [copy and swap idiom](//stackoverflow.com/a/3279550):

```
friend void swap(string &a, string& b)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(a.data, b.data);
    swap(a.m_size, b.m_size);
}

string& operator=(string str)  {
    std::clog << "Copy assignment" << std::endl;
    swap(*this, str);
    return *this;
}
```

Writing it like this means that you don't need to overload it on `const string&` and `string&&` - passing by value will construct `str` using the appropriate constructor.  See the linked answer for details.

Copy-and-swap does have some performance cost to gain that simplicity and safety.  See Scott Meyers's article *[Drawbacks of Implementing Move Assignment in Terms of Swap](https://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html)* for a full explanation.  If that's a concern, then you should keep the overload for move-assignment.

### Append operator

You use `strcat()` to append the second string to the first, but that assumes that both are null-terminated.  You need to use `memmove()` (preferably `memcpy`) for both:

```
string& operator+=(const string & str) {
    size_t new_size = m_size + str.m_size;
    char * new_data = new char[new_size];
    memcpy(new_data, data, m_size);
    memcpy(new_data+m_size, str.data, str.m_size);
    delete[] data;
    m_size = new_size;
    data = new_data;
    return *this;
}
```

The ostream operator also depends on a trailing NUL, so here's a safe replacement:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const string& s) {
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < s.m_size;  ++i)
        os << s.data[i];
    return os << "\n";
}
```

### Addition operator

Addition is conventionally a `const` method; I'm not very fond of casts:

```
string operator+(const string & str) const {
    string s{*this};
    return s += str;
}
```

You may prefer to add a constructor taking two (or more - you might employ `std::initializer_list` or C++17 fold expressions) `string` objects, to save allocating temporary space which is immediately freed and reallocated:

```
public:
    string operator+(const string & str) const {
        return {*this, str};
    }

private:
    string(const string& a, const string& b)
        : data{new char[a.m_size + b.m_size]},
          m_size{a.m_size + b.m_size}
    {
        if (a.data)
            memcpy(data, a.data, a.m_size);
        if (b.data)
            memcpy(data+a.m_size, b.data, b.m_size);
    }
```

That concatenation constructor could be more concise if you swap the order of `m_size` and `data` in the class.

### Tests

It's great that you include the tests in the review.  It helps show how you expect your class to be used, and it helps identify tests you've missed.  In my opinion, all review requests should include tests.

Here I changed the initializer of `a` to not include its NUL and that of `b` to use my additional constructor:

```
string a(p1,sizeof t1-1);
string b(p2);
```

I took out the assignment `e=d;` so that I could test `operator+()` with the empty string:

```
std::cout << "a+e:\t" << a+e;
std::cout << "e+e:\t" << e+e;
std::cout << "e+a:\t" << e+a;
```

It would be worth implementing the `==` operator soon, and then you could make the tests self-checking (affecting the exit status, rather than requiring manual inspection).

## Output

It's not necessary to stream `\r\n` to the standard streams; these are streams opened in text mode, which should do any necessary conversion of `\n` to the target platform's conventions.  The only time you're likely to need `\r\n` is when implementing Internet protocols that require the CR regardless of host platform (you should have the stream in binary mode then, so you don't get `\r\r\n`).

I guess that the output in the constructors is temporary, to help with debugging (though really we should be using `std::clog`, not `std::cout`).  But it causes a problem, because it prevents us marking move-construct and move-assign as `noexcept` - which they should normally be.

I don't know why the streaming operator is private and also writes a newline.  It should be public, and write only the string itself.

Comment: An additional observation: `operator+=()` can avoid some allocations.  Check  if `*this` is empty (`return *this = str;`) or if `str` is empty - `return *this;`.